# SQLite primary key on multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, ddl, composite-primary-key

What is the syntax for specifying a primary key on more than 1 column in SQLite ?

Comment: This is also called compound key http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key

Comment: @OneWorld Or composite key, if any of the columns isn't a key itself.

Answer (score 992, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), specifically [`table-constraint`](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html), it's:

```
CREATE TABLE something (
  column1, 
  column2, 
  column3, 
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);
```

Comment: Well, this is right, but according to the documentation, CREATE TABLE something (column1 PRIMARY KEY, column2 PRIMARY KEY); should be possible as well, but it is not.

Comment: @Yar The docs say "If there is more than one PRIMARY KEY clause in a single CREATE TABLE statement, it is an error." Yes, the railroad diagrams might indicate that is valid as well, but the text below clarifies that it is not.

Comment: Remember to add the *PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)* part at the end like in this answer. If you try to add it after column2 definition you will get a **syntax error**.

Comment: @vovahost It's because there are *two different* productions for **PRIMARY KEY**: One is **column-constraint** within **column-def**, and the other is **table-constraint**. Both use different syntax, so only the latter (at the end) allows a list of columns.

Answer (score 190):

```
CREATE TABLE something (
  column1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  column2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value,
  PRIMARY KEY ( column1, column2)
);
```

Comment: Doesn't Primary Key impose a NOT NULL?

Comment: @pratnala In standard SQL, yes. In SQLite, `NULL` is allowed in primary keys. This answer emphasizes that if you want more standard behavior, you need to add the `NOT NULL` yourself. My answer is just the very basic syntax for a multi-column primary key.

Answer (score 53):

Yes. But remember that such primary key allow `NULL` values in both columns multiple times.

Create a table as such:

```
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE something (
column1, column2, value, PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2));
```

Now this works without any warning:

```
sqlite> insert into something (value) VALUES ('bla-bla');
sqlite> insert into something (value) VALUES ('bla-bla');
sqlite> select * from something;
NULL|NULL|bla-bla
NULL|NULL|bla-bla
```

Comment: Is there any reference to the reason of such behavior? What would be a good way to dump several rows in the database and still remove duplicates, even if they contain `NULL`?

Comment: @Pastafarianist http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html - "According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. [...] NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs."

Comment: Yes, in SQL NULLs always compare false. Because of this, relational theory specifically excludes NULL as the value of any key component. SQLite, however, is relational practice. It seems the authors chose to pragmatically allow the multiple but not "equal" keys. Clearly it's preferable not to allow NULLs as key values.

Comment: Actually *this is not an answer*, but a response to a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685672/6607497 which is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/734704/6607497. Probably too late for the administrators now.

Answer (score 45):

Basic :

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    columnA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    columnB INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (columnA, columnB)
);
```

If your columns are foreign keys of other tables (common case) :

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    table2_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    table3_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (table2_id) REFERENCES table2(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (table3_id) REFERENCES table3(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (table2_id, table3_id)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id
);
```

Answer (score 17):

Primary key fields should be declared as not null (this is non standard as the definition
of a primary key is that it must be unique and not null). But below is a good practice for
all multi-column primary keys in any DBMS.

```
create table foo
(
  fooint integer not null
  ,foobar string not null
  ,fooval real
  ,primary key (fooint, foobar)
)
;
```

Comment: True.  [SQLite calls out](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_primary_key): _According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. [...] SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column._  Hence it's required to pass `NOT NULL` for all primary key columns if using SQLite.

Answer (score 14):

Since version 3.8.2 of SQLite, an alternative to explicit NOT NULL specifications is the "WITHOUT ROWID" specification: [[1](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)]

```
NOT NULL is enforced on every column of the PRIMARY KEY
in a WITHOUT ROWID table.
```

"WITHOUT ROWID" tables have potential efficiency advantages, so a less verbose alternative to consider is:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  c1, 
  c2, 
  c3, 
  PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2)
 ) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

For example, at the sqlite3 prompt:

  `sqlite> insert into t values(1,null,3);
  Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: t.c2`

Comment: For anyone reading this nowadays: `WITHOUT ROWID` has additional implications, and it should not be used as an alternative to writing `NOT NULL` next to your primary key.

Comment: I always specify `NOT NULL` for `PRIMARY KEY` irrespective of `WITHOUT ROWID` since it's explict, doesn't change with defaults and save me from remembering quirks of SQLite. [Related comment on Ken Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns#comment129693789_12925089).

Answer (score 7):

The following code creates a table with **2 column as a primary key** in SQLite.

**SOLUTION:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id TEXT NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    pet_name TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In another way, you can also make the *two column primary key* `unique` and the *auto-increment* key `primary`. Just like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157337

Answer (score 2):

`PRIMARY KEY (id, name)` didn't work for me. Adding a constraint did the job instead.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (
    id INTEGER, name TEXT,
    user INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (user, id)
)
```