# SQLite multi-Primary Key on a Table, one of them is Auto Increment

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have multiple (composite) primary keys on a table and one of them will be auto increment. However, interestingly SQLite allows usage of `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword just after an obligatory `PRIMARY KEY` keyword.

My query is:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     seat TEXT, payment INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (id, seat))
```

However the error is `table "ticket" has more than one primary key`.

Actually I can avoid other primary keys for this table. But I am coding an ORM framework (hell yeah I'm crazy) and do not want to change structure of `PRIMARY KEY` constraint generation for a table (because it is allowed in MySQL afaik).

Any solutions to this?

Comment: I think you meant to say "only" after instead of "just" after?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible.

You can create a `UNIQUE INDEX` which has essentially the same effect as a PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_index ON "table1"("field1","field2");
```

Besides, I fail to see the logic of your schema, that is -> if a column is autoincrement and you don't intend to mess with the values manually, it's going to be unique anyway, so it makes a good simple short primary key. Why the composite? You may have good reasons to make another index on the combination of columns, though.

Comment: Let's say I have one primary key on a table, should I generate an index for this primary key or is it generated internally?

Comment: Yes, the key is automatically an index. See this [short text](http://developer.mimer.com/documentation/html_92/Mimer_SQL_Engine_DocSet/Basic_concepts4.html) on why this is so.

Comment: +1 for the bit on autoincrement. Indeed, if it's autoincrement, it doesn't need to have another field tagging along in the primary key.

Comment: If you want to (manually) replicate the database, then the autoincrement column won't necessarily be unique between copies of the database.  If you add a second column to the row indicating the unique id of the server it was generated on, this resolves such a conflict.

Comment: @Michael - I agree, I see composite keys being useful for replication scenarios. I remember having to tackle such an issue with Drupal 6 a few years back. A properly engineered solution could have been a composite key consisting of insertion_id + server_id. 

Interesting, thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: IMHO, a PK that is a surrogate-key....and using a (different) unique constraint is the best option.  You don't have to "copy" multiple columns for this PK to be a FK in another table.  And it is easier to refactor (in the future) a unique constraint over trying to fix a multi column PK.  Upvote for this answer.

Answer (score 31):

`UNIQUE INDEX` alone doesn't have the same effect as `PRIMARY KEY`. A unique index will allow a NULL; a primary key constraint won't. You're better off declaring both those constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     seat TEXT NOT NULL, 
     payment INTEGER,
     UNIQUE (id, seat));
```

You should also think hard about whether you really need to accept NULL payments.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I was able to implement auto-increment for SqLite with composite keys with syntax exactly the same with SQL Server:

Use **`IDENTITY (1,1)`**

```
create table [dbo].[Person]
{
   ID int IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
   CompositeID1 int not null,
   CompositeID2 int not null,

   constraint [pk_person] primary key clustered (ID asc, CompositeID1 asc, CompositeID2 asc)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also write like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY,
     seat TEXT, payment INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (id, seat))
```

Comment: do not answer the question, 'id' field is not auto incremented