# Error when creating a table in SQLite database with composite primary key at AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: android, sqlite

Mycode

```
    final String createtabBook="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BookMark(lid INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,  bookdir TEXT , lastaddress TEXT,addresname TEXT PRIMARY KEY(bookdir,lastaddress));";
    db.execSQL(createtabBook);
```

Logcat:

```
03-05 18:29:31.708: I/System.out(17160): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BookMark(lid INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,  bookpath TEXT , lastchapter TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(bookpath,lastchapter));
```

i just want to create a table with composite primary key so that it is a combination of bookdir and lastaddress, also i want to make the lid as auto increment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite multi-Primary Key on a Table, one of them is Auto Increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154730/sqlite-multi-primary-key-on-a-table-one-of-them-is-auto-increment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the value of any column autoincrement you need to write it or declare it as primary key.

In SQLite a column declared **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement**.

**EDITED:**

As you can not define more than one `PRIMARY KEY` in a table you have to make the `bookdir,lastaddress` columns as `UNIQUE`  and define the `lid` columns as `PRIMARY KEY` as below:

Try out as below:

```
 final String createtabBook="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BookMark(lid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
  bookdir TEXT , lastaddress TEXT,addresname TEXT, UNIQUE(bookdir,lastaddress));";
```

Also add `","` after the column `addresname TEXT,` in your query.

Comment: @laalto Now what is the problem i did change.

Comment: Consider using a tool such as sqlite3 to check your syntax. Also, there is the keyword `autoincrement` and it has specific place in syntax.

Comment: @laalto I did changed my answer now its fair revoke your vote. I have checked its fine now.