# sqlite in Android insert new row with some values repeated

Tags: android, sqlite

:I have this table:

```
id            |      name          |      chapter      |    book

 1                  hamlet                  I               Hamlet

 2                  Ismael                  IV              Moby Dick
```

The behaviour  I expect for new values is:

Same name && same book    =>  Character exists so Same id than the existing one:

```
 2                   Ismael                   X              Moby Dick
```

Same name && different book   => Character doesn't exist so Changes the id:

```
 3                   Ismael                  XX              The Bible
```

My question is:

Do I have to make the query before insert new values and then insert the new value?

or there is a way to do it in a automatic way by setting up a trigger or something?

My CREATE TABLE statement

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE characters (id INTEGER NOT NULL , 
   name TEXT NOT NULL , chapter TEXT NOT NULL , book TEXT NOT NULL );");
```

Comment: Hi butelo, could you please post your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: done, it's quite simple actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most elegant way of doing so would be for you to isolate the properties of your rows which permit to identify them UNIQUELY. Lets say for instance that name + book make the line unique, then you could concatenate these strings into one identifier in your object, add a column to your database, put and index on it and search on this index when you want to insert new elements.

Comment: Yeah I'll do it that way. I've just assumed that like we have a constraint for Unique values we could also have ways to manage repeated ones. So there's no way to do it the way I ask? just for documentation pourposes.

Comment: unicity is ensured by primary keys if I'm not mistaken so you could also declare the pair (name, book) as primary key. I might suffice. Something like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns

Comment: well actually it would have to be three values: (name, book, chapter) because same character appears in multiple chapters at the same book