# Unable to update the EntitySet '...' because it has a DefiningQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC 4 and C# 4.5 with EntityFramework 4.

I have setup a simple Many to Many table:

`tblAdminUser -> tblAdminUserRole <- tblAdminRole`

When I try to add a role to the admin user, I get the following error:

> "Unable to update the EntitySet 'tblAdminUserRole' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

The code I am using is:

```
this.Role = new tblAdminRole()
{
    Name = "__role__",
};

context.tblAdminRoles.Add(this.Role);
context.SaveChanges();

this.AdminUser.tblAdminRoles.Add(this.Role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your database, set pair of foreign key to tables in m2m table as primary key.
Then update your model to database.

Comment: You need to set a [compound key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_Primary_Key). In SQLite you do it like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 4):

Please check, if all **ID fields** in `tblAdminUserRole` have been set as **Primary Key** in your SQL database. Then update your model.

If Entity Framework can't figure out the primary key, it will generate a `SELECT` statement but it won't be able to create the according `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.