# Composite key in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, composite-primary-key

How to put a composite key in SQLite?
In SQL Server, we select multiple columns and then Set Primary Key. What is the method in SQLite?

I'm using SQLite Database Browser to manage my DB structure, I don't find the option for putting a composite key in a table or maybe I'm missing something. Will some one help me out with this?

Comment: The same way you do it in any other SQL DBMS.

Comment: how?? I tried it, gives me an error

Comment: then why didn't you put any information in your question about what you tried and what the error was?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sqlite primary key on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a `PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3)` constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. SQLite doesn't support changing a table's primary key after it's created (which is a bit of a silly idea anyway).

Comment: it's not that silly if you ponder the point of having a composite primary key in the first place