# "Insert if not exists" statement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, constraints, sql-insert

I have an SQLite database. I am trying to insert values (`users_id`, `lessoninfo_id`) in table `bookmarks`, only if both do not exist before in a row.

```
INSERT INTO bookmarks(users_id,lessoninfo_id) 
VALUES(
    (SELECT _id FROM Users WHERE User='"+$('#user_lesson').html()+"'),
        (SELECT _id FROM lessoninfo 
        WHERE Lesson="+lesson_no+" AND cast(starttime AS int)="+Math.floor(result_set.rows.item(markerCount-1).starttime)+") 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT users_id,lessoninfo_id from bookmarks 
            WHERE users_id=(SELECT _id FROM Users 
            WHERE User='"+$('#user_lesson').html()+"') AND lessoninfo_id=(
                SELECT _id FROM lessoninfo
                WHERE Lesson="+lesson_no+")))
```

This gives an error saying:

> db error near where syntax.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

If you have a table called memos that has two columns `id` and `text` you should be able to do like this:

```
INSERT INTO memos(id,text) 
SELECT 5, 'text to insert' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM memos WHERE id = 5 AND text = 'text to insert');
```

If a record already contains a row where `text` is equal to 'text to insert' and `id` is equal to 5, then the insert operation will be ignored.

I don't know if this will work for your particular query, but perhaps it give you a hint on how to proceed.

I would advice that you instead design your table so that no duplicates are allowed as explained in [`@CLs answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343100/1047662) below.

Answer (score 620):

If you never want to have duplicates, you should declare this as a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarks(
    users_id INTEGER,
    lessoninfo_id INTEGER,
    UNIQUE(users_id, lessoninfo_id)
);
```

(A primary key over both columns would have the same effect.)

It is then possible to tell the database that you want to [silently ignore records that would violate such a constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO bookmarks(users_id, lessoninfo_id) VALUES(123, 456)
```

Comment: What is the optimal way to then get the ID of the newly inserted row or the already existing one, so I can insert it to another table that has a foreign key to this one?

e.g. I have two tables `person (id, name unique)` and `cat (person_id, name unique)` and I want to insert lots of pairs `(person_name, cat_name)`?

Comment: Reading the ID of an existing row is possible only with a SELECT query. But this is a different question.

Comment: Perhaps adding `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` to `CREATE TABLE` would be a bit more handy

Comment: @CL. What will happen if I do not specify `UNIQUE` while creating a table, but I have the first column `id` as a primary key? I checked, it does not update the values if I try to insert anything with the same `id` with `INSERT OR IGNORE`. So, do I need a `UNIQUE` constrain if I have a PRIMARY KEY or is there is anything I'm missing?

Comment: @rightaway717 "Ignore" means that nothing happens; this question has nothing to do with updating.

Comment: It works without "OR IGNORE" to be added for insertion. In fact I'm calling the built-in function SQLiteDatabase.insert(...) directly, so I hope my DB is ok, isn't it?

Comment: @Hack06 Android's insert() behaves differently; you should replace it with [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) or [insertWithOnConflict()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)).

Comment: "A primary key over both columns would have the same effect", how would this be created? Presumably this is what you have in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/734704

Comment: Bear in mind that with `INSERT IGNORE` you will lose insight if query fails, which may mean you are silently losing data. That's not what database are designed for. Use: `INSERT IGNORE` only if you're fully aware of the consequences.

If possible, use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` instead (SQLite 3.24+ required), for any older SQLites `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 ... FROM WHERE ...)` is safer... even though is pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 58):

For a unique column, use this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tableName (...) values(...);
```

For more information, see: [sqlite.org/lang_insert](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Comment: This does not work for me. it always inserts as in  insert or replace into my_table (col1, col2) values('1','2');  will add multiple rows of 1  2

Comment: I might add that it does work well if the constraint is put in place `Unique(col1,col2)` and you also have col3, because an insert or ignore would fail where this will update col3 to the new value. `insert or replace into my_table values('1','2','5')` replaces a row `'1','2','3'`

Answer (score 7):

```
insert into bookmarks (users_id, lessoninfo_id)

select 1, 167
EXCEPT
select user_id, lessoninfo_id
from bookmarks
where user_id=1
and lessoninfo_id=167;
```

This is the fastest way.

For some other SQL engines, you can use a Dummy table containing 1 record.
e.g:

```
select 1, 167 from ONE_RECORD_DUMMY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked for non unique columns (here "Name"):

```
CREATE TABLE InsertDemo ( ID INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT )
    
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO InsertDemo (ID, Name)    -- insert first row
    VALUES ( ( SELECT ID FROM InsertDemo WHERE Name = 'Miller' ), 'Miller' );    
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO InsertDemo (ID, Name)    -- but no second
    VALUES ( ( SELECT ID FROM InsertDemo WHERE Name = 'Miller' ), 'Miller' );
        
SELECT Count(ID) FROM InsertDemo;   -- returns 1
```