# Doesn't insert if row exists

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I do an insert to database using [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/exists.php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite) example, but I've got an error message: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object.
If I do `INSERT INTO participants(email) VALUES ('$email')` evrething is OK. Where is my mistake?

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:participants.db');
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO participants(email) SELECT $email WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM participants WHERE email = $email);");
$insert->execute();
```

**UPD:**

This is what `var_dump($insert)` gives:

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(65) "INSERT INTO participants (email) VALUES ('paekov@gmail.com')"
}
```

Comment: You could use sqlite feature `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO participants(email) VALUES ('$email');`

Comment: can you post what `var_dump($insert)` gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan I updated post with result.

Comment: @sectus this one also insert row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your query needs some modification.

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:participants.db');
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO participants(email) SELECT :email WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM participants WHERE email = :email)");
$insert->execute(array(':email' => $email));
```