# SQLite 'IF NOT EXISTS' syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

None of the other questions which address this error seems to work for me. My query is:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Configuration WHERE key = 'CookieCount')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Configuration (key, value)
  VALUES ('CookieCount', '0')
END
```

and my error message is: "could not prepare statement (1 near "IF": syntax error)"

I have this working in Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b14ef/2/0
But this does not work in SQLite and I need it to work with both.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a procedural SQL system like `IF` and `BEGIN`. For this, though, you can probably use `INSERT ... SELECT` with a `WHERE` condition that checks if the key exists or not.

Comment: The code as shown in your question won't run in Postgres either (and it's not the code you have in the SQLFiddle).

Answer (score 3):

SQLite doesn't have an IF operator like that, at all. Nearest thing is the CASE... http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case, but that doesn't really apply in your situation.

The answer in ["Insert if not exists" statement in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite) applies here, as an insert-if-not-exists statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like this instead IF statement :

```
INSERT INTO Configuration (key, value) 
SELECT 'CookieCount', '0' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Configuration WHERE key = 'CookieCount');
```