# sqlite3 INSERT IF NOT EXIST (with Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, insert

First of all, I am really super-new so I hope that I will be able to post the question correctly. Please tell me if there is any problem.

Now, here is my question: I would like to fill a database with a data, only if it doesn't already exist in it. I searched for this topic and I think I found correct the answer (you can read one example here: [["Insert if not exists" statement in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite])) but I need to write these simple command line in python.. and that's my problem. (I anticipate that I am quite new in Python too)

So, here is what I did:

```
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO ProSolut VALUES('a','b','c')")
    self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ProSolut")
    self.cur.execute("WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProSolut WHERE VALUES = ('a','b','c'))")
```

and here's the error:

```
[ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:125 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1142022496:/ProSolutDB_11: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/albehavior.py", line 113, in _safeCallOfUserMethod     func(functionArg)   File "<string>", line 45, in onInput_onStart OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

so basically I think there is some problem with the bracket "(" in the 3rd string. --> ("OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error")

I know that probably it's a stupid error.
If you can help me, I would really appreciate.

Thank you so much

---

E.G.: I forgot to say that I am using the **software Choregraphe**, which uses the Python language to construct all the functional blocks.
That means that, even if the language is basically Python, sometimes the semantic is not perfectly the same.
I hope that this post can help someone in the future.

Comment: You should use only one SQL statement.

Comment: You are using entirely different SQL commands; the VALUES and FROM clauses are wrong.

Comment: Thank you both of you.. but it would be really helpful an example, if you have time :)

Comment: Did you intend the `SELECT *` and the `WHERE NOT ...` to be part of the same statement?

Comment: Is `a, b, c` the primary key of the table? You could use `INSERT OR IGNORE`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, exactly

Comment: @Barmar I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe it's not the primary key?

Comment: thank you so much guys, @asongtoruin fixed my problem :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `a` is in a column called "Col1", `b` is in "Col2" and `c` is in "Col3", the following should check for the existence of such a row:

```
self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ProSolut WHERE (Col1=? AND Col2=? AND Col3=?)', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
entry = self.cur.fetchone()

if entry is None:
    print 'No entry found'
else:
    print 'Entry found'
```

This selects all entries in `ProSolut` that match these values. `fetchone` then tries to grab a result of this query - if there are no such matches then it returns `None`.

**EDIT:** In line with Barmar's comment, to make this insert the values, adapt to the following:

```
self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ProSolut WHERE (Col1=? AND Col2=? AND Col3=?)', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
entry = self.cur.fetchone()

if entry is None:
    self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO ProSolut (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (?,?,?)', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
    print 'New entry added'
else:
    print 'Entry found'
```

You'll need to make sure you `commit()` your changes too!

Comment: Where is the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to combine everything into a single `self.cur.execute()` call. Each call to this must be a complete query, they're not concatenated to each other.

Second, you can't have both `VALUES` and `SELECT` as the source of data in an 
`INSERT` query, it has to be one or the other.

Third, you don't want to select from your table as the source of the data, as that will insert a new row for every row in the table that matches the `WHERE` expression (which is either all or none, because the `WHERE` expression doesn't refer to anything in the row being selected). You just want to select the values by themselves.

```
this.cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO ProSolut (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProSolut WHERE col1 = 'a', col2 = 'b', col3 = 'c';
    """)
```

Replace `col1`, `col2`, `col3` with the actual names of the columns you're filling in.

If any or all of the columns are a unique key in the table, you could just use `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
this.cur.execute("""
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ProSolut (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
    """);
```

Comment: This appeared as I was constructing my answer and looks much more comprehensive.

Comment: the problem is that maybe in Choregraphe it's a little bit different.. but I will check how much I can adapt this code, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

this is my way out of this problem

```
    for x in y:
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?)", (x["key1"], x["key2"]))
        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Next, ", error)
```

I don't know if it is a good way to solve this, but it worked for me. It will throw an error every time the primary key is not unique