# Insert into SQLite database if not exist in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to add value into SQLite database only if it not exist in database with Java using if statement. I am totally confused.

```
try{

                String econ = String.valueOf(txt_economic.getText());
                String malami = "Select * from MPA1 where econcd = ?";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(malami);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

                String econcdi = rs.getString("econcd");


                if(econ.equals(econcdi) ){

           try{
                     //Insert goes here
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, and correct at least compilation errors. Also you missed parameter for you prepared statement.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: here is an example                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite

Comment: There's quite a few unmatched braces here...

Comment: and never ever swallow your exceptions `}catch(Exception e){
}`