# I am getting syntax error in c# application in inserting values using Where clause

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new 
    SQLiteConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connectionstring);
            string CMM = "INSERT INTO ALARM  (ALARM_ID, ALARM ) SELECT 
       1,'TEMP' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FLAG FROM ALARM WHERE FLAG = 0)";

            cmd.CommandText = CMM;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

i am getting this error near "SELECT": syntax error i could not resolve this issue . this query is running fine in sqlite browser.Please Help me out Thanks in advance

Comment: What should the query do?

Comment: Could you give details about the *exact* error message? Or is it really just "Syntax error near SELECT"?

Comment: Define the string as `Verbatim string literals`. So prefix `@`. Like `@"INSERT INTO ALARM  (ALARM_ID, ALARM ) SELECT 
       1,'TEMP' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FLAG FROM ALARM WHERE FLAG = 0)"`

Comment: Still not working same syntax error

Comment: Are you sure you are using sql lite and not sqlserver? your query looks identical to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337206/1275832

Comment: @ Daisy Shipton near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: Yes i am using sqlite3

Comment: Don't know if it's correct, but let's put a space after `Exists` after `(` .:)

Comment: @ user1672994 still not working

Comment: `SQLiteCommand` is initialized with connection string instead of command text. Update the line as `SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CMM, con)`; And remove the `cmd.CommandText = CMM;
            cmd.Connection = con; con.Open();`. Read this doc for SQLLiteCommand object definition -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.-ctor?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteCommand__ctor_System_String_

Comment: Can you please write the whole code because in this SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CMM, con) i have given connectionstring of databse path

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to miss a `from` where you get the data from:

```
INSERT INTO ALARM  (ALARM_ID, ALARM ) 
  SELECT    1,'TEMP' 
   FROM somehwere -- you where missing this.
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FLAG FROM ALARM WHERE FLAG = 0)
```

Or you just want to insert a single set of values:

```
INSERT INTO ALARM  (ALARM_ID, ALARM ) 
VALUES (1, 'TEMP')
```

Comment: Query insert values if the FLAG value is = 0 FLAG is another column .INSERT INTO ALARM  (ALARM_ID, ALARM ) SELECT 1,'TEMP' from ALARM WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FLAG FROM ALARM WHERE FLAG = 0) i tried this but getting same error error near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: It's not correct, why the query require from clause when constant values are being inserted? Also, SO mentioned that query works in sqllite browser.

Comment: @user1672994 maybe user wants to insert x amount of values from other table, seems illogical but still it could be the case.

Comment: insert into ALARM  (ALARMID, ALARM ) values (1,'TEMP') WHERE NOT EXISTS(select FLAG from ALARM where FLAG='0') This query also not working error near "WHERE": syntax error