# inserting an item into a table if it doesn’t exist SQLite3

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert a (hard coded) new user into a database if the username does not already appear. In the code below, I am trying to have sql check if the user already exists and if so select (or do nothing), otherwise,  insert the new user into the table. I have tried coding this a number of ways, but no matter what I do, the table doesn’t populate! Any tips or ideas would be super helpful thank you so much. For reference, I am using the sqllite3 extension for the language C, and I am using the sql_exec function to make the query.

Attempt 1:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * PERSON WHERE USERNAME='name') BEGIN SELECT 1 END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345') END;
```

Attempt 2:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345') ) END ;
```

Attempt 3:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345') )
```

Attempt 4:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345') );
```

Attempt 5:

```
I F NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 WHERE USERNAME='kat') BEGIN INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345') END;
```

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Insert if not exists" statement in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite)

Comment: Just add a unique constraint on that field.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to add a primary key on your table for the USERNAME field and then to execute the following request with the ON CONFLICT clause:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) 
VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345')
```

See: https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Answer (score 0):

Make Username field as Primary Key or Unique Key so that the username will not be inserted if it is duplicated.

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS, SIGNATURE) 
VALUES('name', 'password', 'ONLINE', '12345')
```