# sqlite3 syntax for creating rows with 2 always unique column values

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I have a table **"statistic"** that contains ***guild_id, category and number***

I need to create rows with values that takes my func, but they need to be both unique:

[image: table]

If 1 column value and 2 column value are same: skip

This is my code:

```
    def save_statistic(self, category: str,
                   guild_id: int):
    self.c.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic 
                   (statistic_channel_id, category, number) 
                   VALUES ((?), (?), 0)
                   ''', (guild_id, category,))
```

I don't really know sql syntax, I need it only for this function

Comment: Please see the answer on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337029/insert-if-not-exists-statement-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case I used UNIQUE in creating statistic table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statistic (
guild_id integer,
category char(255),
number integer,
UNIQUE(guild_id, category)
                                      );
```

then this code works:

```
self.c.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic 
                   (guild_id, category, number) 
                   VALUES ((?), (?), 0)
                   ''', (guild_id, category,))
```