# how to insert the same record but different value in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have 2 columns in sqlite which are name and date,name is already set it to unique to avoid duplicate entry but my problem is I want to insert the same record for column 'name' but different record in column 'date'. I'm also using this to filter the duplicate record and it worked.

```
try {
    dbOpenHelperss.insertOrThrow("table", values);
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e)
    //to detect if there is a duplicated item
}
```

For example in column_name='Peter Xavier' column_date='02/15/14 and i want to insert record of Peter Xavier with different date like column_name ='Peter Xavier' , column_date='02/16/14

What I tried so far is

```
if(!"column_date".equals(colum_name)) {
    //to compare two columns are not the same then insert                               
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("column_name",name );
    values.put("column_date", date);

    try {
        dbOpenHelperss.insertOrThrow("table", values);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) { 
        // to detect if there is a duplicate entry
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the `unique` of `name` column. And use new column for avoid duplicates. ex: id.

Comment: as  Gunaseelan said..if you want to insert duplicate value in name column then why you define it unique ??just remove unique constraint from name column ..

Comment: thanks for the reply, what i mean is i will not be able to insert record if column_name and column_date are the same..i will be able to insert if column_name and column date are different

Answer (score 2):

Add Composite key.that means column_name and column_date together work as a key

Unique (`column_name`, `column_date`) ,

Comment: thanks, i will try this now, im searching for an hour but no luck,ill post here if this work

Comment: unfortunately i cannot add a primary key =( i hope there is a work around

Comment: i created a new table because the sqlite does not have a function of alter, so basically i created a new one but there is an error when i use ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2) it says cannot add one or more primary key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns check this out

Comment: it does not work when  the _id is a primary key.. so what i did was  create table mytable (_id INTEGER,name TEXT,date TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (name,date)) is this okay it doesnt matter if the _id is not a primary key? anyway thank you for your time sorry i cannot upvote due to low reputation..

Comment: in ur statement date and name should be not null.have u done it

Comment: i did it like this create table table(_id INTEGER,name TEXT NOT NULL,date TEXT not null, PRIMARY KEY(_id,name,date)); it insert duplicate item.. but when i remove the primary key of _id.. the name and date are work together or should _id also not null?

Comment: u should keep _id not null