# SQLite Create table with multiple Primary key in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Kindly guide me. how to define both columns as primary key in this way.

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDEE +
                        " (" + COLUMN_Att_Event_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        COLUMN_Att_Email + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY)");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one Primary keys should be declared separately. Query is written in a format question is asked.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDEE +
" (" + COLUMN_Att_Event_ID + " TEXT," +
COLUMN_Att_Email + " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(" + COLUMN_Att_Event_ID + "," + COLUMN_Att_Email + "))"
```

If the table has only one PRIMARY KEY then

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDEE +
" (" + COLUMN_Att_Event_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
COLUMN_Att_Email + " TEXT"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this -

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  column1, 
  column2,
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);
```

Comment: I needed the answer in a query format used in question. Otherwise your answer was available at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns) 
Anyway thanks