# How to prevent duplicate data in android sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Iam working on sqlite database in android i want to insert a table like below

```
                    id procode  proname user
                    1  pro123   mobile   120
                    2  pro123   mobile   121
                    3  pro345   watches  120
```

in the above table only id is uniq all values are not uniq but i dont want to allow same data for same user it means another user will insert same data
now i dont want to insert duplicate while checking  data of procode and user
means like bwlow

```
                    id procode  proname user
                    1  pro123   mobile   120
                    2  pro123   mobile   121
                    3  pro123    mobile   120
```

in the above table 3 is duplicate data

Comment: make procode as primary key.

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns for more than one primary keys in your data base

Comment: procode can use for other user

Comment: i updated my qu please check

Comment: Before you insert a new row, do a query to check if that data already exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you insert new row you have the new USER.

So before inserting data into your DB.

**Check whether already same USER data exists or not.**

Below is SQLITE Query hint for the same

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user="YOUR_VALUE", null);
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
 showMessage("Error", "Record exist");
}
else
{
 // Inserting record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique key when you create your table

```
CREATE TABLE name (<your column definitions>, UNIQUE (procode, proname, user) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```

To handle what happens on a conflict, see https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best solution in the process of trial and error
In the Main Activity

```
 int count = 0;
        while(db.findTask(results.toUpperCase()).moveToNext()){
            count++;
            break;
        }
        if(count!=0){
            Snackbar.make(v, "Name Already Taken", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            return;
  }
```

And in the DataBase

```
public Cursor findTask(String taskName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+ID+ " FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+
            TASK_NAME + " = '"+taskName+"'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c=databasemanager.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + **TABLE_NAME** + " WHERE " + **COLUMN_NAME_IN_WHICH_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING** +" = " + "'"+**what are you searching**+"'", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
//            showMessage("Error", "Record exist");
        }
        else
        {
            // Inserting record
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_IN_WHICH_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING , what are you searching);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME ,null, cv);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).