# Can multiple columns count as one combined primary key?

Tags: sqlite, primary-key

There's a village where villagers visit multiple houses. I want to store which villager visits which house, and how often they visit it. I decided to create the table as follows;

`CREATE TABLE 'visitis'('villager' TEXT NOT NULL, 'house' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'amount' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);`

The table is stored as follows;

- `villager` stores the villager's name. Each villager has a unique name.
- `house` is the address of the house. This is an integer.
- `amount` stores how many times that villager has visited that house.

This table does not contain a primary key, and is thus, what I consider, not optimal. Both the amount of villagers and the amount of houses is undefined to a level that it is no longer efficient to store the villagers or the houses as a column.

Multiple rows may contain the same villager name, and multiple rows may contain the same house address. The only known uniqueness, is that the **combination** of villager and house is unique. Hence I wondered if there was a method to use the two columns as a shared primary key. This could save a lot of time, but I'm not sure if SQLite is capable of doing this.
If not, is there a better method to do this? I have the conditions that;

1. Most villagers will visit multiple houses. However, this amount is relatively small and can be assumed to be below 50 houses;
2. There are a lot of houses (integers) that will not be visited. However, the houses that *are* visited, will often be visited by up to 10 villagers;
3. Villagers will visit a limited amount of houses, with but a few visiting over 1000 houses;
4. It is important to store how often which villager has visited which house;
5. Data needs to be accessed often by both the villager's name and the house's address number;
6. Both the amount of houses and villagers can get very high.

Perhaps I'm missing something obliviously obvious. Am I...?

Comment: Hi. The only CK (candidate key)  here is {villager, house}. That's the only possible PK if you decide you want one. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. PS This is not clear: "Both the amount of villagers and the amount of houses is undefined to a level that it is no longer efficient to store the villagers or the houses as a column." Do you mean something re reducing string storage by the implementation? Do you know that you have described a table with a row for every possible villager-house pair? Are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. (Eg google your title with 'site:[so] sqlite'.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite primary key on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

The primary key of this table would seem to be the combination of the `villager` and `house` columns.  SQLite has no problems with a primary key consisting of more than one column:

```
CREATE TABLE visitis (
    villager TEXT NOT NULL,
    house INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (villager, house)
);
```

The logical reason for this is that a given villager visiting a given house needs to be represented by only a single record.  The `amount` column handles the case where there could be more than one visit.

But while this fixes your immediate problem, it is not ideal, because your table is not normalized.  The `visitis` table is what is usually referred to as a junction table, because it connects two other tables in some meaningful way.  Here is a better design:

```
CREATE TABLE visitis (
    villager_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    house_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (villager_id, house_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (villager_id) REFERENCES villages (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (house_id) REFERENCES houses (id)
);
```

Now we only persist pairs of foreign keys, each of which points to a record in the `villages` or `houses` table.  This way, we don't duplicate any data.

Comment: Normalization above 1NF replaces a table by projections of it. It.does not introduce new columns. Under common sense the question's table is in 5NF. It can't be normalized further. This "duplication" is an implemention-based notion that has nothing to do with normalization, involving ids not being "duplicated" even though other values in the same places would be "duplicated", and is for data compression & related performance. Ironically, reducing "duplication" increases redundancy.

Comment: @philipxy The title question is whether SQLite supports a primary key consisting of multiple column.  The answer is yes, and I have stated why this is the case.  If you are suggesting that the OP should additionally store duplicated information, then you should explain why.

Comment: That comment doesn't address my comment. Mine says that the alternate design is *not* from normalizing. (Which doesn't add ids.) (Or address insert/delete anomalies--but if that's part of the re-design, it unjustifiably assumes that the original design is wrong & that it doesn't store rows with 0.) PS You don't say what exactly is to be stored in the new tables but once we have separate tables for villagers & houses we would typically (presumably per non-"duplication"--whatever that is) not store villager-house pairs with 0 visits, whence 0 seems a problematic default.