# Non-unique primary keys in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, primary-key

I am trying to recreate a word list database by [The Norwegian Language Bank](https://www.nb.no/sprakbanken/en/resource-catalogue/oai-nb-no-sbr-5/) in SQLite from the following table diagram:

[image: Norsk Ordliste table diagram]

I assume **PK**, **FK** and **PF** are abbreviations for **Primary Key**, **Foreign Key** and **Primary/Foreign Key** respectively. Each table is a separate CSV file from [this](https://www.nb.no/sbfil/leksikalske_databaser/ordbank/20220201_norsk_ordbank_nob_2005.tar.gz) archive, but for simplicity's sake I will only address the `BOYING` table in this question. First I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "BOYING" (
  "LOEPENR" integer NOT NULL,
  "BOY_NUMMER" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "BOY_GRUPPE" varchar(32),
  "BOY_TEKST" varchar(32),
  "ORDBOK_TEKST" varchar(32)
);
```

Then I add the list of elements (shortened):

```
INSERT INTO BOYING (LOEPENR,BOY_NUMMER,BOY_GRUPPE,BOY_TEKST,ORDBOK_TEKST) VALUES
(1,1,'substantiv','ent ub','entall_ubestemt'),
(2,2,'substantiv','ent be','entall_bestemt'),
(3,3,'substantiv','fl ub','flertall_ubestemt'),
(4,4,'substantiv','fl be','flertall_bestemt'),
(5,1,'verb, normal','inf','infinitiv');
```

The error is caused by fifth element having the same value as the first element, resulting in `UNIQUE constraint failed: BOYING.BOY_NUMMER`. Primary keys have to be unique, so how did The Norwegian Language Bank build this database, and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: There can only be one PK so if 2 columns are marked P(K) then the pair is the PK & it is pairs that must be unique. But you yourself say "PK, FK and PF are abbreviations for Primary Key, Foreign Key and Primary/Foreign Key" so why did you only define a one-column PK? And why is LOEPENR there? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite primary key on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete commments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram might be a simplified version that does not reflect the full way they are using it. Primary keys only work if they are unique. In case the most logical column to use for this is not unique though, it can be combined with another column. If the combination of these column is unique, they can together become a 'composite key'.

In this case that might be BOY_NUMMER and BOY_GRUPPE together. To make this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "BOYING" (
  "LOEPENR" integer NOT NULL,
  "BOY_NUMMER" integer NOT NULL,
  "BOY_GRUPPE" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  "BOY_TEKST" varchar(32),
  "ORDBOK_TEKST" varchar(32),
  PRIMARY KEY ("BOY_NUMMER", "BOY_GRUPPE")
);
```

Or, if LOEPNER is unique:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "BOYING" (
  "LOEPENR" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "BOY_NUMMER" integer NOT NULL,
  "BOY_GRUPPE" varchar(32),
  "BOY_TEKST" varchar(32),
  "ORDBOK_TEKST" varchar(32)
);
```

Comment: Composite key was the answer.